# Ubuntu 18.04 ETS - Update Apache to 2.4.58

Tags: ubuntu, apt, apache-httpd, software-updates

We are using a Ubuntu 18.04 server for a service which will be retired later this year, and will not function above this version. Whereas the ideal solution would be to upgrade the OS, due to resource constraint we are just going to us this for another few months. I offer this info to explain that migration to later Ubuntu is a non-starter.

The problem is that the apache update in Oct 2023 to Apache 2.4.57 appear to have been the last for this version of Ubuntu. This means that Teneble is throwing its dummies out the pram and wants an update to Apache 2.4.58 and my security team are weeping under their desks in sheer terror at this missing update

Is it possible to do a manual update on Ubuntu 18.04 or add a custom repo for APT to use to update apache with later patches.

Comment: So you don't know how to upgrade apache but you know its a lot more effort than upgrading the entire OS? Of course its possible to replace the current Apache installation - but it is MUCH more work and much riskier. Upgrading the entire OS might simply take a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

End of life for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is June 2023. The extended support (ESM) for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is April 2028. You can see the releases end of life(s) on [wiki.ubuntu.com](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) page. Maybe see if this program has the update you need (I do believe so but as I'm not a member of this program I can't check myself)

Going from there I believe that if your company has a security team, they must be aware that this would be the best possible route for them. Otherwise I would say that they simply don't have enough awareness on security but this topic has already been touch by [Marcus Müller](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/767222/310756). I would draw the same conclusions.

While these two other options won't totally solve your issue, they may still be of interest in a last resort situation:

- Use a Web Application Firewall (WAF) in front of your application if you don't have one already. This might play in the realm of risk management for your company, and should be a minimum if you need to keep a outdated version of your web server.
- there is a lot of reasons while this could fail, but you can also see for the option of compiling and packaging the updated version of Apache yourself. there is a lot of caveats though because using an old version of a Distribution may generate a lot of issues with libraries dependencies, and additional work for modules, plugins, etc.. that you may need.

edit: Another option would be to see if you can have a container image using a more up to date version of Apache, on that system that you want to keep. You mileage may vary though but that can be an alternative too.

Answer (score 1):

No. If there's no updated Apache release from Ubuntu, then there's no updated Apache release.

If your security team is worth their money, they can go and take Ubuntu 18.04's apache packaging and apply the patches themselves, giving you an updated Ubuntu package. Alternatively, they can make your software work on a more modern Ubuntu. The fact that you're now in this situation where security whines about an outdated server version is an organizational failure where resources were not assigned to updating your system to work with secure underpinnings; the role of a security team is to proactively find such problems *before* they manifest. So, unless they've been pestering you for more than 2 years about this by now, it's actually partially their fault, for not doing their job very well.

I believe in computer security that is active and helps the teams that do productive work, and thus become part of what creates value, and not just someone who subscribes to security vulnerability lists – a stupid program can do that.

Comment: It does infuriate me when they give me a raw tenable report and that report clearly has 'there is no known exploit for this' and yet it's STILL listed as high. Our security team only exist to make work for others and not analyse the threats and then put pressure on with fake 'this COULD happen' to terrify management

Comment: It's fine, that's literally their job, but you need to tell management that a good security team would actually have proactively informed you two years ago and now are of no help actually assessing the security implications aside from reporting something that they themselves didn't understand. They *could* work with the teams, they *choose* not to.